# How to solve this Error on UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Loading image URI like google Image search results with UIWebview will show "Received memory warning" and crashed for continues running about 1 hour. Did I miss something in my webview creation?

```
NSString *loadURL =/****Some Image search result****/;
 [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:loadURL]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The memory warning is not only the fault of your application it is also due to the another applications which are running in the background. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377887/memory-warning-and-crash-how-to-handle-it)  stack overflow question for more information.